How to use artifacts from previous stage in TBC semantic release componenet publish stage?
I am trying to pass an file artifact from my build stage to the TBC semantic release component publish stage so that I can rename it and add it as a release asset.
When I run my pipeline it shows that the artifact was correctly saved in the build stage. In the publish stage with the semantic release job it fails because it cannot find the artifact file that was saved in the build stage.
Is it possible to make the artifacts from previous stages usable in the semantic release job?
I have checked that the previous stage did save the artifact by looking at the Gitlab pipeline viewer.
I have tried another TBC component and it correctly uses the previous stage artifacts. The gitlab ci package TBC component correctly loads the artifacts from the previous stage as expected. Below is the portion of the log where this happens:
Downloading artifacts 00:01
Downloading artifacts for build-pdf (8367422461)...

But if I look at the semantic release job log the artifact download does not occur.
